Android Java Serial Port Communication
I am developing a project with Java language on an Android device. I need to connect via serial port from COM port, but I get "SecurityException" error. I am using Android 11 version device. I am waiting for your support.
My code is here:
SerialPortFinder serialPortFinder = new SerialPortFinder();
System.out.println(serialPortFinder.getAllDevicesPath());
SerialHelper serialHelper = new SerialHelper("/dev/ttyS0", 57600) {
     @Override
     protected void onDataReceived(ComBean comBean) {

     }
};
serialHelper.setPort("/dev/ttyS0");
serialHelper.setBaudRate(57600);
serialHelper.setDataBits(8);
serialHelper.setStopBits(1);
serialHelper.setParity(SerialPort.PARITY.NONE.getParity());
serialHelper.open();

The error I got:


You probably need to request user's permission as explained in the docs: https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/usb/accessory#permission-a

In the future, please post stack traces as text, not images. Note that SerialHelper and SerialPortFinder are not part of the Android SDK, and so we will have difficulty helping you with them.

Looking at a possible src of referenced SerialPort shows the circumstances of the SecurityException: the device canRead() or canWrite has failed. Perhaps this can help refine your question.  Check (English version) the FAQ section as this adb command is required evidently (which sets permission on the tty device).
